# Should I attach this working place to my CV?

Tags: career-development

I’m working on my current company for about 3 months as a junior developer. But problem is I don’t want to work here anymore because of some myself career path and seeking for full-time a remote job. I don’t know how to tell it to my mentor and my boss. They help me a lot during past 3 months.

Is there too weird to work only 3 months? Can I attach this working place to my CV?

Comment: It's not weird to only work 3 months. If you don't include it in your CV, they will ask: "What have you been doing for the past 3 months?" so you may as well include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don’t know how to tell it to my mentor and my boss.

There is no need to tell them anything until you're ready to resign.

> Is there too weird to work only 3 months? Can I attach this working
> place to my CV?

Yes you can, according to your last question you're leaving because of educational openings overseas so need a remote job. This is a perfectly valid explanation if asked why you only lasted 3 months.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will start seeking for a remote job first.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely, you should list this current company in your resume or CV.

You can describe the length of time you work for this company as "**From February 2022 to Present**". (Note: You wrote that you are still working for this company on your post. So, you have not quit yet.)

There are at least 2 good reasons to list this company on your resume:

1. It shows that you are actively employed. Job applicants who are
   actively employed seem to be more attractive to prospective
   employers than those who are not actively employed.
2. You are still actively employed by this company. So, it is a good practice to show this info to prospective employers in case they hire
   you and want to do a background check on your work history either before or after they give you a job offer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, including it is much more likely to help you than omitting it, because an unexplained gap in your CV can be suspicious. (Were you unemployed? Incarcerated? Or do you have a job that would look even worse than those??) That's something that would almost certainly come up in an interview (if it got that far).

A very short period of employment doesn't look great, but it's not necessarily a red flag, as long as:

- You can provide a reasonable explanation of why it's so short. (This could be along the lines of “I didn't fit into the company culture,” or “The work wasn't what I was led to expect.”)
- You don't have *many* short periods of employment.

Basically, you need to allay a prospective employer's suspicions that you might be quitting *them* in a few months too.

And, as explained in many other answers on this site, it's usually better not to say anything to your current employer until you have a signed offer that'd you'd be prepared to accept. (And almost always far better not to resign until then!)